# tex4ht: bot symbol in hypertarget

Tags: symbols, tex4ht

I use `tex4ht` to compile my document.

However I have one problem with `$\bot$`symbol.

Command

```
\hypertarget{Symbol$\bot$test}{UserText}
```

leads to compilation error:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted
```

Could someone help me to resolve this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `\hypertarget` takes two arguments: `\hypertarget{name}{text}`.  Also `name` must only contain ASCII symbols.

Comment: Cannot we handle this? Why then Latex compiler successfully compiles such code? But tex4ht does not...

Comment: Why would you want to handle this?  This will result in a broken link.  What is the point of having *link names* with LaTeX math symbols?

Comment: Combination: \hypertarget{Symbol$\bot$test}{TargetText} \hyperlink{Symbol$\bot$test}{LinkText} works as expected in case with Latex compiler.

Comment: I just had a look into the `tex4ht` source code.  It is not possible to use `\bot` in the link name, because `tex4ht`'s modified `hyperref` uses the link name to make a control sequence using `\csname ...link name... \endcsname`.  It is a law of TeX, that between `\csname` and `\endcsname` only characters must remain, but `\bot` expands to `\mathchar"23F`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Could you make answer out of your comments?